# Securing assets folder in express js node

Tags: node.js

I have an assets folder in which i have images and render them with node express js. Is there a way to secure the assets in such a way that the users access only the assets entitled to them?

```
const app = express();
app.use('/assets', express.static('assets'));
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server runnning on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: Yes, first get familiar with middleware, then at some point you inspect the current requesting user, and look up their permissions wherever you have them configured (file, db, etc) for the resource they are trying to load - ultimately its an if/else just like the one answer that exists here, but a little fancier; maybe instead of `!req.user` its a function `canAccess(uri, currentUser)`

Comment: Sure will work on it... Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are looking for authorization middleware which will take care of checking the access.

You can use [passport](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/) js or any other library or create your own.

Since you are using Express to code, this snippet may be useful.

```
        requireLogin = (req, res, next) => {
        if (!req.user) {
            return res.status(401).send({ error: 'You must login!' });
        }
        next();  
 }; 
     app.get('/assets',requireLogin , express.static('assets'));
```

Express has very good documentation on middleware [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) .

Comment: One more question..... What will the correct way to have a lookup for files and it's entitled user... Thanks for the response... Will work on your solution.

Comment: I am not sure your objective, but file access and user access are both separate things. You should have a module for access control and use it whenever trying to retrieve file. For looking up files use any fs module provided. e.g. fs or fs-extra etc.

Comment: no i meant.. consider a user objct and it has an image field.... say his profile pic... im trying to implement the logic to restrict the user only to the images entitled to him.

Comment: IMO you should separate out image load module, write api for just image like /image/xyz.png within this api you can check access and if no access show no image.